# Cannot use GCC's builtin functions on Cortex-A9

Tags: gcc, arm, built-in, cortex-a

For an embedded project (bare-metal) I need to use memc** functions.Though I haven't
disable the builtin functions I always get a linker error; e.g:

undefined reference to `memcmp'

no matter if I use: memcmp or __builtin_memcmp!

Is there anything I missed to enable the builtins?

My compile options are:  -g -Wall -mcpu=cortex-a9

Comment: You say it's 'bare metal' - do you link a C library?

Comment: gcclib doesnt include C library calls right you need the C library.   try adding -lc at the end? or maybe that is in the linker -Xlinker -lc?  or just dont use C library calls for bare metal since you dont have an operating system with which to implement the library.

Comment: No. I must not link the C library; that's why I wanted to use the builtins...I thought that I can use the memcpy/memcmp functions without relying on the C lib.

Comment: sure memcmp/cpy/set, etc are not operating system dependent but other C library calls are...

Comment: @dwelch: So is there any way to use these builtins or not?

Comment: yes, you have to link them in which means you need the magic incarnation depending on how your tool was built, where installed, etc.  sometimes just add the full path to the library file if all else fails.

Comment: ld doesnt know where it was spawned from, gcc does so although it leaves a bad taste using a compiler as a linker (in a case where you are probably overriding the linker script and possibly the bootstrap meaning linker commands) you can more often get it to work using gcc to do your linking (And get gcclib and libc to link in).  you also needed to actually install and/or build libc which is not part of a gcc build.  binutils, gcc, libc, gdb are often four separate builds.

Comment: if you just downloaded a toolchain it should all be there (well not gdb necessarily).  you can make your own mem* functions with a different name to avoid confusion and just use those.  can make them from scratch or pull those functions from a library and then control them and not have linking problems, etc.  There are solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__builtin` is a bit of a lie.  It will optionally use a built-in implementation, if it exists.  Otherwise it will call the library functions.  You will need to provide implementations of these functions, either in your own code or in a C library.  Note that "a C library" doesn't mean a full OS libc, there are plenty of bare metal C libraries that don't include OS-dependent functions.